# Export path information into file

Tags: csv, export, file-io

I have a table tbl_parameter which contains path information in field value like

```
keyword       value

calculation   \temp\example.csv

iterations    100
```

If I export the table to a csv file via

```
SELECT keyword
       ,value FROM tbl_parameter
INTO OUTFILE 'c:/temp/parameter.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I receive a double \ into the csv file

```
calculation;\\\temp\\\example.csv

iterations;100
```

How can I disable the double \ ?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You should change the escape character from `\` to `|` for instance.

So your code should looks like that:

```
SELECT keyword
       ,value FROM tbl_parameter
INTO OUTFILE 'c:/temp/parameter.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```